# Save current div id on cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this code:

```js
$(function games() {
  // Different timeouts for each div
  var times = [4000, 5000, 5000, 8000, 8000];
  var counter = 0;
  divs = $('#tuk1, #tuk2, #tuk3, #tuk4, #tuk5');

  function showDiv() {
    // hide all divs, filter current index, and fadeIn
    divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(0);
    // set time out duration from array of times 
    setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter]);
    // cycle the counter     
    counter = (counter + 1) % divs.length;
  };
  showDiv(); // show first div    
});
```

How could I modify it to save the last DIV viewed by the user on a COOKIE?
I searched for a long time, I do not find, please..

Comment: All you need to do is store the current `counter` in a cookie, right? In which case [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript) contains all you need

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hello, thanks for your reply. I check this question but i dont undertsand :/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cssLayout() {
    document.getElementById("tuk").href = this.value;
}


function setCookie(){
    var date = new Date("Februari 10, 2013");
    var dateString = date.toGMTString();
    var cookieString = "Css=document.getElementById("tuk").href" + dateString;
    document.cookie = cookieString;
}

function getCookie(){
    alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Like that ?